# Sending Any File to localhost

Tags: c#

I want to keep the database Files only on the server so when i upload a file i want to send it to "127.0.0.1"  i tried the following code

```
private void SendFile(string fileName = "C:\\test.txt")
{
    IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

    Socket client = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    client.Connect(ipEndPoint);

    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

    client.Send(fileBytes);

    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    client.Close();
}
```

But it keep getting me this Error : **"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "** Which Means Server is not listening.

So,

1) How fix this in order to be able to send any file to localhost

2) How i can open files in the browser via "127.0.0.1[FileName].[Ext]"

Comment: Do you have anything listening on port 11000 on that machine? Is the firewall allowing the connection?

Comment: What server is not listening?

Comment: The result i got from searching about this problem was that server is not listening, this is my first time dealing with socket and networks, so am not quit sure what to do .

Comment: @user3808010 This is not how you handle networking. Dealing with raw TCP is a lot trickier than it seems. Why not use something that already works, like WCF or FTP, or perhaps even network shares? What are you trying to send anyway? It seems like you're doing a lot of things wrong. Why not use an actual shared database, instead of manually synchronizing text files? Sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: The story is like this, i have multiple clients and a server, when a client wants to upload an attachment i want to save it only on the host, can be any thing like image + txt + word + rar and any other. I want to use socket and when i try to connect it gets this error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: @user3808010, it's because there is nothing listens on 11000 port of that machine. You need to write an server-side too. Also you are trying to connect to same host that code runs from - it's very strange part - maybe there is mistake, and you really want to connect to some REMOTE host?

Comment: Right now i want to start the server and then make clients send stuff, and i appreciate any help right now :.

Comment: Is this a web server receiving files or something else?  Is the code above client-side code to run in an application?

Comment: Yes, sending files to the host , the above is client code ,

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something to listen to the port using the SocketServer class. The code you wrote expects a server to be listening to a connection in the 11000. This is done using the Listener.Listen() method. A full example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx